# pandas delete row unless strings from two columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe like this:

```
ref     leftstr           rightstr
12      fish 10           47 red A45
49      abc bread x10     green 12
116     19 cheese 19A     blue blue 4040
118     8 fish 9fish      A10 red B11
200     cheese 000        99 green 98
240     142Z cheese B     blue 42 12
450     bread 94.16       0.6 red blue
...
```

And a large list like this:

```
li = [
    '47 red A45 bread fish 10',
    'cheese 000 [purple] orangeA 99 green 98',
    'bread 94.16 green 12',
    '0.6 red blue abc bread x10',
    'bread 19 cheese 19A 100 blue blue 4040',
    '8 fish 9fish 0.6 red blue',
    'bread fish 10 red A45'
     ...
     ]
```

I want to delete rows from the df if the exact strings in leftstr and rightstr are not both present in any item (but it has to be the same item) of the list. It doesn't matter whether leftstr or rightstr appear first in the list item, or if there is text in the list item as well as leftstr and rightstr.

```
Desired output:
ref     leftstr           rightstr
12      fish 10           47 red A45
116     19 cheese 19A     blue blue 4040
200     cheese 000        99 green 98
```

So, for example, ref 49 is deleted because, although leftstr and rightstr are both in a list item, they are not in the same list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
# Identify rows to keep
rows_to_keep = []
for item in li:
    for i, row, in df.iterrows():
        if row["leftstr"] in item and row["rightstr"] in item:
            rows_to_keep.append(row["ref"])

# Select rows
filtered_df = df[df["ref"].isin(rows_to_keep)]

print(filtered_df)
# Outputs
   ref        leftstr        rightstr
0   12        fish 10      47 red A45
2  116  19 cheese 19A  blue blue 4040
4  200     cheese 000     99 green 98
```

Comment: All of the other solutions work (thanks everyone), but I've gone for this one as it's closest to what I had been trying and makes the most intuitive sense for me (as a newbie).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
get_idx = lambda s: next((idx for idx, item in enumerate(li) if s in item), np.nan)

to_keep = [ref_val
           for ref_val, left, right in df.to_numpy()
           if get_idx(left) == get_idx(right)]

ndf = df.query("ref == @to_keep")
```

where the `get_idx` function finds the index of the given a string `s` in the list `li` by checking against each item of `li`. We use `next` for short-circuiting.

Then a list comprehension over the values of the frame looks at each pair of `left` and `right` strings of `leftstr` and `rightstr` columns: is the index they reside in `li` the same? Then keep the corresponding `ref_val` into a list.

In case a string is not found at all in `li`, `get_idx` returns `np.nan` supplied as the default arg to `next`. Since `np.nan` compares not equal to itself, we are not including the `ref_vals` whose neither `leftsr` nor `rightstr` was found. Lastly we query the frame with the `to_keep` ref values to keep only those,

to get

```
>>> ndf

   ref        leftstr        rightstr
0   12        fish 10      47 red A45
2  116  19 cheese 19A  blue blue 4040
4  200     cheese 000     99 green 98
```

---

(if you don't want to use NumPy only for `np.nan`, you can replace it with `float("nan")`.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `merge` and list comprehension. First cast your list into a test df, then use `str.extract` and `map` to look for ref in original df with `leftstr`:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"name":li})

test["ref"] = (test["name"].str.extract(f'({"|".join(df["leftstr"])})', expand=False)
                           .map(df.set_index("leftstr")["ref"]))

print (test)

                                      name  ref
0                 47 red A45 bread fish 10   12
1  cheese 000 [purple] orangeA 99 green 98  200
2                     bread 94.16 green 12  450
3               0.6 red blue abc bread x10   49
4   bread 19 cheese 19A 100 blue blue 4040  116
5                8 fish 9fish 0.6 red blue  118
6                    bread fish 10 red A45   12
```

Now do a `merge` and finally use list comprehension with `zip` on `rightstr`:

```
new = df.merge(test, on='ref')

print (new[[x in y for x, y in zip(new["rightstr"], new["name"])]])

   ref        leftstr        rightstr                                     name
0   12        fish 10      47 red A45                 47 red A45 bread fish 10
3  116  19 cheese 19A  blue blue 4040   bread 19 cheese 19A 100 blue blue 4040
5  200     cheese 000     99 green 98  cheese 000 [purple] orangeA 99 green 98
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip` the columns `left_str` and `right_str`
then iterate over the zip object inside a list comprehension which yields tuples containing `left` and `right` strings then for each string `s` in `li` test for the presence of `left` and `right` in `s` in order to create a boolean mask

```
mask = [next((True for s in li if l in s and r in s), False) 
             for l, r in zip(df['leftstr'], df['rightstr'])]
```

---

```
>>> df[mask]

   ref        leftstr        rightstr
0   12        fish 10      47 red A45
2  116  19 cheese 19A  blue blue 4040
4  200     cheese 000     99 green 98
```